# Не открывается меню при зажатии на ссылку на смартфоне IPhone

Tags: html, css, ios, safari

Проблема с IPhone Safari

Есть каталог с товарами. В каталоге каждая карточка состоящая из текста и картинки обернута в ссылку . По идее при зажатии пальцем на карточку, не важно на картинку или текст, должно вылезать дефолтное меню браузера (https://i.stack.imgur.com/kshe2.jpg). Но вместо этого если зажимать картинку она увеличивается, а если текст то он выделяется. При это если просто тапнуть на карточку то все отработает нормально, по ссылке перейдёт. На андроид все нормально, меню открывается.

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: на картинку попробуйте навесить pointer-events: none;, а на текст cursor: pointer; на мобильном медиа

Comment: @EkaterinaRatatui на картинку навесил pointer-events: none;, на IPhone теперь при зажатии картинка выделяется как будто текст. cursor: pointer; уже есть